# How do I get a line chart to display properly in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, chart

I'm trying to graph the year against the day, which I store in 2 lists. However, my graph shows up empty when I run my code, but when I manually put in the values that are output for ChartData2, I do get the graph I want. I checked to make sure the values were being pushed correctly and make sure they're integers, which all checked out. How do I fix this? Code is below.

```
var chartData = [];
var chartData2 = [];
//var chartData2 = [5,8,11,29,16,3];


for (var yr = 2014; yr <= 2019; yr++) {
  var data = charttodata(yr.toString());
  chartData.push(yr);
  chartData2.push(charttodata([yr.toString()]));
}
print(chartData);
print(chartData2);


var placeMarkerButton = ui.Button({
  label: 'Place Marker',
  onClick: function() {
var chart = ui.Chart.array.values(chartData2, 0, chartData)
  .setChartType('LineChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Year vs. First Close Year',
    hAxis: { title: 'Year' },
    vAxis: { title: 'DOY Start' },
  });
print(chart);
}
});
Map.add(placeMarkerButton);
```